# Automating the creation of Composite Bundle Archive file

Tags: websphere, osgi

I have my code checked-in in an SVN repository. 
I need to create composite bundle archive (CBA) from the checked-in code.
Is there any command / tool that I can use to automate the CBA creation process?
My projects are not Maven projects.

Comment: What's a "composite bundle archive"??

Comment: I googled it and discovered it's something specific to IBM Websphere. Maybe you should try the websphere mailing lists, or contact IBM tech support.